# Any good books and/or tutorials on XML-based APIs, REST, SOAP with Python?

Tags: python, xml, web-services, soap, rest

What are some good books and/or tutorials on XML-based APIs, REST, SOAP with Python?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Chapters 9, 11, 12 from [Dive into Python](http://diveintopython.nfshost.com/toc/index.html) by Mark Pilgrim deal with these topics. Though the book is outdated, you can give it a try if you are *just starting out*. Some of the libraries used in the book haven't been updated in few years.